# i want to search for a key and take the value

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I have a `$blablablabnla = 8` and an array :

```
$blab-la = array(
    [3] => apples
    [4] => bananas
    [8] => lemon
)
```

and i want to get me out lemon just this i want to make.any ideas?
could someone help me?

Comment: This is PHP 101, how to access an array element! (Just wait a minute and you will get the usual vampire answers)

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and look at Example #6 (Accessing array elements)

Comment: You cannot use this `$blab-la` as variable name in PHP, how do you even compile ?

Comment: Sometimes this place can be a really harsh environment for someone who is just looking for some help. Be nice, we were all beginners once.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the key -

```
echo $blabla[$blablablabnla];
```

It will print - `lemon`

You also need to remove the `-` from the variable name. `-` is an operator.

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

[Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Not gonna cut it, syntax error in the variable name.

Comment: @RobForrest Thanx for pointing it out.. Missed that one. :)

Comment: I wonder why OP has to remove the hyphen from his variable name...

Comment: @Rizier123 there are some rules to define a variable names and i think you know about those rules.

Comment: Maybe I know, but it seems like OP doesn't

Comment: Maybe.. That's why added the explanation.

Comment: No, you added it , because someone pointed it out to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394444/i-want-to-search-for-a-key-and-take-the-value#comment48877466_30394471 otherwise the answer would still be incorrect

Comment: Right. I missed that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably struggling with this as you can't use hyphens in PHP variables. Try:

```
$blab_la = array(
    [3] => apples
    [4] => bananas
    [8] => lemon
)

echo $blab_la[$blablablabnla];
```